# Oracle query slow while all data has returned to client

Tags: oracle

We have a oracle 11g database

when execute a query with pagination, sometimes it take 170+ seconds to finish.

here is the query:

```
SELECT 
    CUST_ID, 
    CUST_ID CUST_NO, 
    CASE 
        WHEN HO.LEADERFLAG='1' 
        THEN '*'||SUBSTR(HO.CUST_NAME,2)||'(行长回收)' 
        ELSE '*'||SUBSTR(HO.CUST_NAME,2) 
    END CUST_NAME, 
    CUST_TYPE, 
    '1' MAN_MAIN, 
    '10'   MAN_MAIN_PAR, 
    CASE 
        WHEN HO.ATTENTION_FLAG = '1' 
        THEN '1' 
        ELSE '0' 
    END ATTENTION_FLAG, 
    USER_ID, 
    FUN_USER_NAME(USER_ID) USER_ID_NAME, 
    ORG_FOR, 
    FUN_ORG_NAME(ORG_FOR) ORG_FOR_NAME, 
    CUST_LVL, 
    CUST_LIFECYC, 
    FUN_PAR_P_NAME('42000', CUST_LIFECYC) CUST_LIFECYC_NAME, 
    CREDIT_P_FLAG, 
    FUN_PAR_P_NAME('40000', CREDIT_P_FLAG) CREDIT_P_FLAG_NAME, 
    DEPOSIT, 
    CUST_IDT_NO, 
    FUN_PAR_P_NAME('12000', CUST_IDT )  CUST_IDT, 
    FUN_PAR_P_NAME('13000', CUST_ENDU ) CUST_ENDU, 
    FUN_PAR_P_NAME('14000', CUST_MARR ) CUST_MARR, 
    FUN_PAR_P_NAME('19000', CUST_VOCA ) CUST_VOCA, 
    FUN_PAR_P_NAME('11000', CUST_GEND ) CUST_GEND, 
    CUST_MOBI, 
    CUST_HOME_ADD, 
    NVL(FINANCIAL,0)       AS FINANCIAL, 
    NVL(CUST_LVL_IN_ALL,0) AS CUST_LVL_IN_ALL, 
    NVL(FINANCIAL_YEAR,0)  AS FINANCIAL_YEAR, 
    NVL(DEPOSIT_YEAR,0)    AS DEPOSIT_YEAR, 
    NVL(PROVIDE_YEAR,0)    AS PROVIDE_YEAR, 
    NVL(FINANCIAL_MONTH,0) AS FINANCIAL_MONTH, 
    NVL(DEPOSIT_MONTH,0)   AS DEPOSIT_MONTH, 
    NVL(DEPOSIT_DAY,0)     AS DEPOSIT_DAY, 
    ROW_, 
    ( 
    CASE 
        WHEN CUST_TYPE = '1' 
        THEN FUN_PAR_P_NAME('200', CUST_DEPART) 
        ELSE FUN_PAR_P_NAME('100', CUST_DEPART) 
    END) AS CUST_DEPART 
FROM 
    (   SELECT 
            ROWNUM ROW_, 
            ho.* 
        FROM 
            cust_merge_info HO 
        WHERE 
            1 = 1 
        AND man_main = '1' 
        AND NOT EXISTS 
            (   SELECT 
                    CUST_ID 
                FROM 
                    CUST_MAN_TEM CT 
                WHERE 
                    ( 
                        CT.STATUS = '10' 
                    OR  CT.STATUS = '20') 
                AND CUST_ID = HO.CUST_ID 
                 
                UNION ALL 
                 
                SELECT 
                    CUST_ID 
                FROM 
                    CUST_UTD_CHK CU 
                WHERE 
                    CU.CHK_STATUS = '10' 
                AND CUST_ID = HO.CUST_ID) 
        AND NODE_PATH LIKE '%,00999,%' 
        AND HO.USER_ID IS NOT NULL 
        AND HO.USER_ID != '00468' 
        AND USER_ID !='GZ'||'00468'
        AND USER_ID !=SUBSTR('00468',3) 
        AND HO.CUST_LVL= '03'
        AND HO.CUST_TYPE= '1' ) ho 
WHERE 
    1=1 
AND ROW_ >= 1000+1 
AND ROW_ <= 2001-1
```

when I test it in plsql, I find that even all 1000 records has been returned to client, the plsql shows that statement's execution is not finished(the red lightning sign is still on)， after almost 177 seconds, it finished.

Any wrong configuration can cause such problem?  please help

Comment: It looks like you are fetching 10,000 rows at a time.  Are you saying that all 10,000 have been returned to the client?  Or that 1,000 of the 10,000 have been returned to the client and there are no more rows that will be returned?  Or something else?

Comment: @JustinCave all 1000 records  returned and no more rows, I have pasted wrong SQL

Comment: my DBA told me that all 270,000 rows are being transfered to client, even client is only showing 1000 matching records, that sounds strange for me.

Comment: By using tcpdump I proved dba is wrong,

Comment: OK.  So the query returns 1,000 rows now (though there is no `order by` so you're asking for an arbitrary 1,000 rows and it's entirely possible that rows would get missed or returned in multiple pages).  You're saying that all 1,000 rows have been returned to the client and there is no more network traffic?  What does "the red lightning sign is still on" mean?  It sounds like you are describing a performance problem on the client rendering the data that has been fetched rather than a problem with the database.